# Show that some ideals are prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> I want to show that the ideals $(x,y)$ and $(2,x,y)$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ are prime ideals.

---

Could you give some hints how we could do that?

Do we have to show that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2,x,y)$ are integral domains?

How could we do that? Could you give me a hint?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Do we have that $\phi :\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is an homomorphism because of the following? $$$$ Let $f(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, then $f(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^{n(j)}\alpha_ix^iy^j$. We have that $$f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^{m_1}\sum_{i=0}^{n_1(j)}\gamma_ix^iy^j+\sum_{j=0}^{m_2}\sum_{i=0}^{n_2(j)}\beta_ix^iy^j=:\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^{n(j)}\alpha_ix^iy^j=:f(x,y)$$ Then $$\phi (f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y))=\phi (f(x,y))=f(0,0)=f_1(0,0)+f_2(0,0)=\phi (f_1(x,y))+\phi (f_2(x,y))$$ We also have that $$f_1(x,y)\cdot f_2(x,y)=\left (\sum_{j=0}^{m_1}\sum_{i=0}^{n_1(j)}\gamma_ix^iy^j\right )\cdot \left (\sum_{j=0}^{m_2}\sum_{i=0}^{n_2(j)}\beta_ix^iy^j\right )=:\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^{n(j)}\alpha_ix^iy^j=:f(x,y)$$ Then $$\phi (f_1(x,y)\cdot f_2(x,y))=\phi (f(x,y))=f(0,0)=f_1(0,0)\cdot f_2(0,0)=\phi (f_1(x,y))\cdot \phi (f_2(x,y))$$

Answer (score 4):

Show that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ using the evaluation map at $0$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(2,x,y)$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by reducing the coefficents of the polynomial modulo $2$. In both cases consider the kernel of the map and use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: To show that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ do we use this mapping? $$f(x,y)\mapsto f(0,0)$$ But how can we show that this is an homomorphism?

Comment: Let $\phi$ be the mapping and note for example note that $\phi(fg)=(fg)(0,0)=f(0,0)g(0,0)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$ because of how the multiplication of functions is defined. Addition is checked similarly.

Comment: Why does it hold that $(fg)(0,0)=f(0,0)g(0,0)$ ?

Comment: Do we have that $\phi$ is an homomorphism because of the following? $$$$ Let $f(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, then $f(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^{n(j)}\alpha_ix^iy^j$. We have that $$f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^{m_1}\sum_{i=0}^{n_1(j)}\gamma_ix^iy^j+\sum_{j=0}^{m_2}\sum_{i=0}^{n_2(j)}\beta_ix^iy^j=:\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^{n(j)}\alpha_ix^iy^j=:f(x,y)$$

Comment: Then $$\phi (f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y))=\phi (f(x,y))=f(0,0)=f_1(0,0)+f_2(0,0)=\phi (f_1(x,y))+\phi (f_2(x,y))$$ We also have that $$f_1(x,y)\cdot f_2(x,y)=\left (\sum_{j=0}^{m_1}\sum_{i=0}^{n_1(j)}\gamma_ix^iy^j\right )\cdot \left (\sum_{j=0}^{m_2}\sum_{i=0}^{n_2(j)}\beta_ix^iy^j\right )=:\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^{n(j)}\alpha_ix^iy^j=:f(x,y)$$ Then $$\phi (f_1(x,y)\cdot f_2(x,y))=\phi (f(x,y))=f(0,0)=f_1(0,0)\cdot f_2(0,0)=\phi (f_1(x,y))\cdot \phi (f_2(x,y))$$

Comment: Looks good to me. The part for addition can be seen easily as when you add two polynomials the constant coefficent of their sum is just the sum of the constants for each. However, the fact that $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is usually taken as a definition of the product of two functions, namely, the pointwise product of two functions is another function, obtained by multiplying the image of the two functions at each value in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

The first isomorphism is proved by observing that any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ can be written as a sum of a constant term, terms involving nontrivial powers of $x$, and terms involving nontrivial powers of $y$. More explicitly, the ideal $(x,y)$ has all polynomials with constant term $0$, i.e., if $f \in (x,y)$ then there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $f(x,y) = xp(x,y) + yq(x,y)$. Now we note that if $f(x,y)$ is an arbitrary polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ then we can write it as
$$ f(x,y) = a_0 + xp(x,y) + yq(x,y)$$
for some $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and some $p(x,y), q(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. In the quotient mapping $\mathbb{Z}[x,y] \to \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y)$ the polynomials $xp(x,y) + yq(x,y)$ get sent to zero. Consequently the identification
$$ f(x,y) \mod{(x,y)}= a_0 + xp(x,y) + yq(x,y) \mod{(x,y)} \equiv a_0 \mod{(x,y)}$$
induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ via the mapping $a_0 + (x,y) \mapsto a_0$ for all $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For the second isomorphism consider the following isomorphisms for (commutative) rings: if $R$ is a ring and $(a) \subseteq R$ is a principal ideal generated by $a \in R$, then there are isomorphisms
$$ (R/(a))[x,y] \cong R[x,y]/(a)$$
so if $p_1, \cdots, p_n$ are any number of polynomials of $R[x,y]$ then
$$ \frac{(R/(a))[x,y]}{(p_1, \cdots, p_n)} \cong \frac{R[x,y]}{(a,p_1,\cdots,p_n)}\cong \frac{R[x,y]/(p_1,\cdots,p_n)}{(a)}.$$
Since we already know $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}{(2,x,y)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y)}{(2)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}.$$